# dart : check if a directory exist

Tags: dart, flutter

In Dart would like to check if a directory exist but without knowing a substring of this directory :

eg :

> dir = preview/1552146038702.jpg.1--001--001.html.test.jpg

I tried :

```
io.Directory(await dir).exists().then((exist){
```

but in the dir I don't know **1--001--001.html**

Any idea?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: 'cause dart is close to js, it was initially built to replace javascript

Answer (score 22):

`Directory.exists()` provides this information

bool exists = await Directory(path).exists();

- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/exists.html
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/existsSync.html

Answer (score 7):

This works for me, hope my answer help

```
final path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download';
final checkPathExistence = await Directory(path).exists();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to import :

`import 'dart:io';`